# How to use Google Plus Integration in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making application and I want to integrate it with G+, to make user login with Google account. To create app I use **Android Studio**.

I read many question and answers on Stack Overflow but I can't fix my app!

**Here are steps I made:**
1. Add *google-play-services.jar* to libs folder of my project
2. Click "Add As Library" on jar file in Android-Studio project explorer
3. Add script to java file from example in the web
4. Add *google-play-services.jar* library to *Build.Gradle* file
5. Starting the app makes it crash

The question is: **How to add Google+ ingeration to application made using Android Studio, am I doing something wrong?, Thank your for you help**.

***Here are my source codes:***

**Java Class:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;

public class StartActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                .build();

        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

        initializeSplashElements();

    }


    ///     ***     ///         PLUS INTEGRATION        ///     ***     ////

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
        // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }

    ///     ***     ///         PLUS INTEGRATION        ///     ***     ///

    (...)

}
```

**Layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".StartActivity"
              android:clickable="false"
              android:background="@drawable/ziel_pomar_tlo">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/splashLogo"
            android:src="@drawable/catch_up_logo_flatten"
            android:contentDescription="@string/catchup_logo_describe"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/loading_3dot"
            android:id="@+id/loadingText"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/loadingText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splashLogo"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:id="@+id/gps_row">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_gps"
                        android:id="@+id/gps_desc"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_gps_settings"
                            android:id="@+id/gps_settings"
                            android:layout_weight="2"/>

                    <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_gps_ok"
                            android:id="@+id/gps_fixed"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/web_row"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_web"
                        android:id="@+id/web_desc"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_web_settings"
                            android:id="@+id/web_wifi_settings"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_web_settings2"
                            android:id="@+id/web_3g_settings"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/loading_screen_no_web_ok"
                            android:id="@+id/web_fixed"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Build.Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/google-play-services.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
        compileSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Google Repository, without import any libs (.jar) in your code

**UPDATE**: if you looking for Google (or third party) library  you can check: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ (by Chris Broadfoot, a Google Developer)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    // compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') // OLD: can remove

    // Other useful library
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'

    // Note: these libraries require the "Google Repository" and "Android Repository"
    //       to be installed via the SDK manager.
}
```

Ref: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf

Comment: Cheers for this. How can we find the last version of the Google Play Services dependency - i.e., to replace the `4.4.52` part with?

Answer (score 0):

Google plus integration in android studio is very simple follow these steps.

1.Add play services dependency to build.gradle.

2.Add json configuration file to your app directory you can get it from [Google Developer console](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

3.Build GoogleSignInOption and GoogleApiClient and start google login on button click..

for more detail you can go through this tutorial 
[Google plus Integration in android studio](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/02/google-plus-integration-in-android-sign.html)